# Code using HttpConnectionResponseContent for unit testing in a .NET 6 solution

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, httpresponsemessage

Here is info about our technical development environment :

•            .NET 6

•            C# 10

•            Visual Studio 2022

I’m trying to Mock System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler in my mock Unit test code.

```
Mock<HttpMessageHandler> handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

       handlerMock
           .Protected()
           // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
           .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
              "SendAsync",
              ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
              ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
           )
        // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
        .Returns(async (HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken token) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Headers.Add("Date", "Mon, 17 Apr 2023 14:55:43 GMT");
            response.Headers.Add("Server", "Warp/3.3.23");
            response.Headers.Add("X-Request-ID", "adaf6342-a007-4155-8480-4cd2eacc3a0b");
                               response.Content =  ….fill-in-blank code…….

            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            //...decide what to put in the response after looking at the contents of the request

            return response;
        }).Verifiable();
```

To get more specific, Microsoft.Net.Http.Client package contains the HttpConnectionResponseContent class ( which inherits from HttpContent ).

In the fill-in-blank code area above, I’m trying to implement something like the following code excerpt:

```
response.Content =  System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent(….)
```

I’ve been searching the internet to find what dll package contains System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent API.
However, it’s a little strange, I found the following github.com link:

https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockerdash/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/Microsoft.Net.Http.Client/HttpConnectionResponseContent.cs

It indicates that the HttpConnectionResponseContent class is part of the Microsoft.Net.Http.Client namespace

However, when I added Microsoft.Net.Http.Client package dll reference to my .NET 6-based solution, it gives the following warning:

```
Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,  
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,   
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1'      
instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully     compatible  
with your project.
```

Furthermore, it shows the problem because when I added the namespace, it states that the following namespace does not exist:

```
using Microsoft.Net.Http;
```

Could someone please post back code and explain how I can implement something along the following sample code?

```
response.Content =  System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent(….)
```

Comment: When I'm trying to write a mock around an http call I use this nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/RichardSzalay.MockHttp. You can set up expectations and make it return what you want.

Comment: `Microsoft.Net.Http` is a .NET Framework package, so you can't use it in modern .NET. Its contents have been essentially superseded by the `System.Net.Http` stuff that is already in it. And anyway, `HttpConnectionResponseContent` is an internal type, so you're not supposed to be able to use it. What are you trying to do? Why do you really want to return that specific type of content? It's for mocking, can't you just use any of other `HttpContent` classes?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thanks for your helpful comment. I've elaborated my technical problem in a separate question posting:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074950/code-test-data-for-httpmessagehandlerpassed-via-httpclient-for-a-mock-unit-tes