# Code test data for HttpMessageHandler(passed via HttpClient) for a mock unit testing of GraphQL Proxy Adapter System Under Test (SUT) code

Tags: unit-testing, graphql, mocking, response, dotnet-httpclient

Here is info about our technical development environment :

•  .NET 6

•   C# 10

•   Hasura GraphQL v2.6.2-pro.1

•   PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

•   Visual Studio 2022

•   "GraphQL" version="7.3.1" Proxy

•   "GraphQL.Client" version="5.1.1" Proxy

•   "GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft" version="5.1.1" Proxy

I am working on .NET AWS Cloud application that contains

- an AWS Lambda Function
- Hasura GraphQL v2.6.2-pro.1
- RDS PostgreSQL

The following diagram show the basic interaction between some of the major components of my solution:

[image]

The “GraphQL Proxy Adapter” is an Adapter( Wrapper) for GraphQL.

The integration tests for the aforementioned solution work properly.

However, for the Mock Unit Testing, it’s a bit of challenge when I  tried to implement GraphQL Proxy Adapter System Under Test (SUT) code.

I’m trying to Mock System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler:

> ```
> Mock<HttpMessageHandler> handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
>
>        handlerMock
>            .Protected()
>            // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
>            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
>               "SendAsync",
>               ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
>               ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
>            )
>         // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
>         .Returns(async (HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken token) =>
>         {
>             HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
>             response.Headers.Add("Date", "Mon, 17 Apr 2023 14:55:43 GMT");
>             response.Headers.Add("Server", "Warp/3.3.23");
>             response.Headers.Add("X-Request-ID", "adaf6342-a007-4155-8480-4cd2eacc3a0b");
>                                response.Content =  ….fill-in-blank code…….
>
>
>                 response.RequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
>                 
>                 
>                     response.RequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", new string[] { 
>                 "application/graphql-response+json", "application/json" });
>                     response.RequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", new string[] {
> "utf-8" });
>                     response.RequestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", new string[] {   
>                     "GraphQL.Client/1.0.0.0" });
>                     
> response.RequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", new string[] {
>     "Bearer" blah blah Bearer Token AlphaNumeric String blah blah
>
>     });
>                      response.RequestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
>                      response.RequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(http://Hasuratest.com/);
>                       response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
>                  //...decide what to put in the response after looking at the contents of the request
>
>                  return response;
>              }).Verifiable();
>
>
>               // use real http client with mocked handler here
>               HttpClient anhttpClientBland = new 
>  HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
>              {
>                  BaseAddress = new 
>  Uri(http://HasuraSingleEndpointtest.com/),
>              };
>
>
>
>       graphQLRequestWrapperMock.Setup(r => r.Query)
>                                     .Returns(@"
>                 mutation InsertInsuranceFiling
>                 ($filer_email_address: String,
>                 $message_id: String,
>                 $filed_date_time: timestamp,
>                 $subject: String,
>                 $insurer_email_address: String) {
>                   insert_sendgrid_status_vw_insurance_filing_one(
>                              object: {
>                         filer_email_address: $ filer_email_address,
>                              message_id: $message_id,
>                            filed_date_time: $ filed_date_time,
>                           subject: $subject,
>                          insurer_email_address: $ insurer_email_address })
>                    {
>                     filer_email_address
>                     message_id
>                     filed_date_time
>                     subject
>                     insurer_email_address
>                     id
>                   }
>                 }");
>
>         graphQLRequestWrapperMock.Setup(r => r.OperationName)
>                                   .Returns("InsertInsuranceFiling ");
>
>         graphQLRequestWrapperMock.Setup(r => r.Variables)
>                       .Returns(new
>                       {
>                           message_id = "TestItOutMessageId",
>                           filer_email_address = zara@ikea.com,
>                           subject = "Resolved",
>                           filed_date_time = DateTime.Now,
>                           insurer_email_address = lebron@lakers.com
>                       });
>
>         GraphQLHttpClient graphQLHttpClientWrapperSUT = new GraphQLHttpClient(graphQLHttpClientOptionsWrapperMock.Object,
>                                                                                              newtonsoftJsonSerializer.Object,
>                                                                                              anhttpClientBland);
>
>
>         IGraphQLResponse<dynamic> graphQLResponse = graphQLHttpClientWrapperSUT.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(graphQLRequestWrapperMock.Object).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
> ```

In the fill-in-blank code area above, I’m trying to implement something like the following code excerpt:

> response.Content =  ……fill-in-code…..blah blah something with "{ blah
> Blah GraphQl Schema  Data
> "data":{"insert_sendgrid_status_vw_email_record_one
> ":{"id":4,"message_id":"blahBlahDataBlahBlah"Encoding.UTF8,
> "application/json"

(As a side question, is it even correct for me to implement mock data code with response.Content or am I supposed to use another variable?)

In any case, how can I properly fill in implement the above code?